# Angular 9 component doesn't change the page although catching the right value in url

Tags: angular

In my below component I've added router links to change the view when the text or the image with the underlying routerLink is clicked. But although the correct value is taken in the url of the browser after each click, the view doesn't change till I manually refresh the page. Have a look at my code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h6 class="text-muted">Recent Blogs</h6> 
      <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="image-parent">
            <a [routerLink]="['/blog', blog.id]">
              <img src="http://localhost/Angular7Blog/api/uploads/{{blog.image}}" class="img-fluid" alt="image">
            </a>
            </div>
              <a [routerLink]="['/blog', blog.id]">{{blog.title}}</a></li></ul></div></div></div>
```

typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recent-blog',
  templateUrl: './recent-blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recent-blog.component.css']
})
export class RecentBlogComponent implements OnInit {
  public blogs;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    let myResponse = this._http.get('http://localhost/Angular7Blog/api/'+'recent_blogs.php').subscribe(
      data =>{this.blogs = data;},
      error =>{console.log("some error occured");
      });}}
```

Client-side module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogDetailComponent } from '../blog-detail/blog-detail.component';
import { RecentBlogComponent } from '../recent-blog/recent-blog.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogDetailComponent}];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecentBlogComponent, BlogDetailComponent ],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  exports: [RouterModule, RecentBlogComponent, BlogDetailComponent]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientModule } from './client/client-routing/client.module';
import { BlogHomeComponent } from './client/blog-home/blog-home.component';

const routes: Routes =[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home',             component: BlogHomeComponent }];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    BlogHomeComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    ClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can u please share app.component.html ?

Comment: Yes! it's as below:
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="removeFooter()"></app-footer>

Comment: share your routing module and app module. without see those can't give a solution

Comment: I've updated them. Have a look now. Please note that the components I'm speaking about is on a different module as ClientModule which I've called in the app.module

Answer (score 0):

In my case i resolved this problem by relaunching (ng serve) the application